# Can't force virtualenv to use Python 3.5

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have been having trouble using the requests package in Python 3.6.5. If I run Python 3.5, it works, but not if I run 3.6.5.

I have been trying to remedy this problem by using a virtual environment, but have not had any luck. I have created the virtualenv using this:

```
mkvirtualenvwrapper -p /usr/local/bin/python3.5 env_test
```

When I activate that environment and type `python -V`, it tells me it is using 3.6.5 still.  When I type `python3.5 -V` though, it tells me it is using Python 3.5.5, and `which python3.5` says it is sourced in my virtual environment folder.

I guess that virtualenv is installing other versions of Python into the environment as well, and using 3.6.5 as the default, which I don't understand why, but I need it to access `python3.5` when I type `python`.  What can I do here?

Comment: Try typing `which python`, and see where it is.  It's very likely a symbolic link, so then `ls -l` the result to see where it's pointing.  If you don't like which symbolic link it's finding, you have something wrong with your `$PATH`.  If you do like where the symbolic link is, but don't like where it's pointing to, re-do the link.  `rm` it, and then `ln -s` appropriately.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein [`which` may not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then), e.g., if the OP has `python` defined as an alias.  `type` would be better here.

Comment: When I type `which python` it tells me it is using /usr/local/bin/python3.6, which is outside the virtual environment.  When I type `which python3.5` though, it tells me it is using ~/.virtualenvs/env_test/bin/python3.5, which is inside the environment.

Comment: `type python` tells me it is aliased to python3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, you have an alias set up, where when you type `python`, it will automatically run `python3.6`.

To get past this, you have to avoid the alias.  You'll have to look up `alias` in the man of your shell.  If it's bash, you could remove the alias by typing `unalias python`, but chance are, this will only work in the shell you're currently in.  Next time you open up a terminal or otherwise have a need to execute your `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`, this will likely execute again.  You could look for where your alias is set in those files, and remove that line.  Or, if the alias gets set in a file outside your control, you could just add `unalias ptyhon` into your .bashrc.

Or, if you want to just temporarily avoid it,enclose your command in ' or ".  `'python'` will avoid the alias.

Once the alias is out of your way, `what python` will likely point you to an area in your virtual env, which should then be a symbolic link to the right version of python.

Comment: This was what I had found out.  I had an alias set in .bash_profile.  Although I figured it out on my own, this was the correct answer.

Comment: Ah.  I wasn't sure from your comment on the question if you knew where to go from there, and since any added explanation would have been an answer, I put it here.  :-)

Comment: Still deserves to be chosen as the correct answer.  :)